# Typecast classes

Tags: c#, class, casting

I have two classes in different namespaces which I need to type cast.

How to type cast object of one class in another. Both the classes have same method and properties.

May reflection will work?
Any example of typecasting of classes will be helpful.

Comment: You can't cast as they are not related in any way. This is a job for something like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Comment: I think you are looking for *mapping*, not *casting*.

Comment: here you have a lot of examples http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/808ad927-385f-49c9-aace-256eefe659d7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast directly from one type to another, you can do:

1. a manual mapping
2. map automatically using reflection (as propery names are the same)
3. Use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast them unless they are related in some way, for example, one is the base of other.

You can map from one to the other in many different ways, one would be by using a mapper, AutoMapper is a well known one

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

This wil map from one to the other based on class member names

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (a part form *mapping*) in case when the classes are not related in *any* way, can be use of `dynamic`. 
Event if this is too dangerous, but can be considered like one of possible options:

```
namepsace A {
    public class NotRelatedA() {
       public void Run() {}
    }
}

namepsace B {
    public class NotRelatedB() {
       public void Run() {}
    }
}


dynamic dyn = new A.NotRelatedA();
dyn.Run(); //Run A

dyn = new B.NotRelatedB();
dyn.Run(); //Run B, without changing and mapping anything
```

Repeat, this is kind of dangerous, as you leave safe static type world, and jump into the dynamic powerfull mess, so if you use it, use it with causion.

Answer (score 0):

How many properties do those classes have? Are they "hand-written" classes?

Maybe you don't need two classes and can delete one of them and use the other one everywhere?

Maybe one of the classes could derive from the other? Then you will only have to write the common properties and method in the base class.

If you need two distinct classes, and neither derives from the other (this is the situation one msut have for "ordinary" casts (reference conversion casts) to be allowed), you have several options:

1. Write a constructor overload for one of the classes that takes in an instance of the other class as a parameter, or
2. Write a static method that "translates" an instance of one class to a new object of the other type, or
3. You could write a `public static explicit operator ClassOne(ClassTwo ct)` that did the "translation". With that, it's allowed to use standard cast syntax (i.e. say `(ClassOne)variable`), or
4. As others have suggested, you could use a mapping tool, or write your own reflection code that finds the properties that "look alike" a translate between them.